# Connecting to paginated APIs using Zapier?

Tags: zapier

Is there a way in Zapier to connect to a system exposing Paginated API to get all data? I am trying to use Custom Javascript code but since that runs on lambda it can max run for 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The easiest thing is to use a custom integration, which supports paging. There's still an execution time limit, but you can get pretty big pages.

See [the docs on the subject](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform/tree/master/packages/cli#paging).